# How to listen for data changes at more than a particular location in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase as real-time DB for mobile APP I'm developing (JS Web SDK), the structure is as below in the screenshot, the key = email, each key have the mobile user information, and GPS coordination of the mobile location inside node = "path"

How to listen on all the the "path" of all the emails (users)?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Straight from the Firebase [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data):

> value: Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a path.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // Do whatever
});
```

This function will run once when it is initiated and the once more for every change to the data under the path. `snapshot` will return all the contents of `user/` which is a lot of data to be returned for every change. You can change the `ref` accordingly.

Comment: Any advice how to listen on many but particular nodes, without listening to the whole tree, as it's huge? My app is like Instagram where I'm got an infinite scroll of elements, and only want to output messages to the needed Photo in real-time, without reloading the whole page of data.

Comment: Honestly, you probably want to restructure your data if its that big in one node.

Comment: Already found a super short and lightweight solution, thanks!

Comment: @Dimitri hey can you share your approach to this problem as an answer if you have other then adding listeners for each path. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can listen to specific events if you want :

```
// Get a reference to the database service
var database  = firebase.database();
var usersRef  = database.ref('whatever/users');

usersRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  console.log('user was added !!');
});

usersRef.on('child_removed', (snapshot) => {
  console.log('user was removed !!' );
});


usersRef.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
     console.log('user was changed !!' ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution in code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your Firebase>/mobile/users");

   users.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                // childSnapshot == mobile/users/email

                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                childSnapshot.forEach(function (path) {
                    if (path.key() == 'path') {

                        //create reference for each path
                        var pathRef = path.ref();

                        pathRef.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {

                            // now you are listening on all "path" under each user/email

                        })
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: This only works if your firebase has no authentication set up, which means your data is public.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get this to work with vite+vue. For any wondering here's what worked for firbase realtime database as of July 11th 2021 after an `npm install firebase`

```js
// main.js
//...
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getDatabase, ref as firbaseRef, onChildChanged} from "firebase/database"
const firebaseConfig = {
    //... copy paste from dashboard: project settings > your apps > SDK setup and configuration > npm
}
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const database    = getDatabase(firebaseApp)
const dbRef       = firbaseRef(database,  `posts/test`)
onChildChanged(dbRef, (snapshot)=>{
    console.log('Content has changed!!');
})
//...
```